# Reverse proxy HTTPS problem with mixed content EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, https, progressive-web-apps, mixed-content

Currently have part a part of an app hosted on server 1 EBS which is HTTPS through a personal domain. Trying to bring in another module that is hosted on server 2 EBS. Server 2 is causing me to get

> ```
>  "bundle.js:49 Mixed Content: The page at [...] was loaded over HTTPS,
>  but requested an insecure resource '[...]/graphql'. This request has
>  been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."
> ```

I understand what the issue is, but just unsure of what direction to go in for possible solutions. Is there a way to reroute the graphql request through my custom HTTPS domain in a way that will avoid the mixed content issue? Pretty new to all of the DNS stuff that I had to do just to get the first EBS and custom domain pairing to work. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: What web server are you using for server #1? If Apache or Nginx you can setup a reverse proxy that talks HTTP to server #2 and delivers content over HTTPS to your clients. The better choice is to make server #2 HTTPS.

Comment: Unfortunately don't have the option to make server #2 HTTPS since it's elastic beanstalk.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html